# Access File In Another Directory (Python)

Tags: python, directory, path, joblib

I tried to access files with `with open` but the files itself located not in the same folder (since I want to access files in many different folders).

```
import os
path = r"C:\Users\M S I\Desktop\TA MACHINE LERANING\MODEL SKENARIO UJI 1" # here contained file "[model joblib 1 1]" until [model joblib 17 24]"
l = os.listdir(path)
for model in l:
    for Coor_X in range(1,18):
            for Coor_y in range(1,25):
                with open('model joblib ['+ str(Coor_X) +' '+ str(Coor_y) +']','rb') as f:
                    print(f)
```

But it keeps telling  **"[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model joblib [1 1]'"**

Comment: Your comment says you have a file named `[model joblib 1 1]` and yet and you're trying to open a file named `model joblib [1 1]`.

Comment: sorry in that comment  i mean the folder contained model joblib [1 1] instead of [model joblib 1 1]

Comment: The path used in *open()* is relative to your current working directory. You probably need to construct an absolute path. Also, when the *open()* succeeds, *print(f)* will almost certainly not give you the results you expected

Answer (score -4):

```
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: How does this add value to the OP's question?